# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: dba.run is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, asynchronous

[image]

I'm working with node and sqlite, trying to connect asynchronously to the db with the sqlite-async node module(https://github.com/fhellwig/sqlite-async/blob/master/sqlite-async.js).

I have the following functions:

```
const Database = require('sqlite-async');

async function asyncdb() {
const dba = new Database;
return await dba.open('./test.db').then(() =>
    console.log('async db opened')
  )
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('async db failed');

  })
```

}

and:

```
async function select_from_table(dba,tablename, limit) {

  let arr = [];
  let sql = `SELECT Id FROM ${tablename} WHERE Type='Real' LIMIT ${limit}`;
  return await dba.run(sql);
}
```

When I run them as in the screenshot:

```
$ node sqlite.js 

(node:12943) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: dba.run is not a function
at select_from_table (/home/optionhomes11/nodeprojects/hayes/sqlite.js:113:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/optionhomes11/nodeprojects/hayes/sqlite.js:141:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(node:12943) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error 
originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by 
rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process 
on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
```

How can I fix this?

edit:

changing code to:

```
const dba = asyncdb();
console.log('out',dba);
```

gives:

```
out Promise { <pending> }
async db opened
```

edit2:

Thank you, but I'm getting syntax errors that say

```
console.log('async db opened');
                             ^
```

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

with your version of the function. Also I tried await and it would not allow it there saying it had to be in async function

[image]

Comment: The value of `dba` is only available for use after the pending promise returned by `asyncdb` is fulfilled. This means either calling `asyncdb` from within an `async` function so the `await` operator can be used on its return value, or from within a `then` handler added to the pending promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not handling the returned database on the `.then()` according to the [documentation example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite-async)

I think that the following should work

```js
const Database = require('sqlite-async');

async function asyncdb() {
const dba = new Database;
return await dba.open('./test.db').then((db) => {
    console.log('async db opened');
    return db;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('async db failed');
  })
}
```

You are also not awaiting for the `asyncdb` function when you call it

```js
const dba = await asyncdb();
console.log('out',dba);
```

Comment: Also worthwhile: the `catch` handler inside `asyndb`  should threw its argument  with a `throw err;` statement instead of returning . `catch` handlers  do not propagate error conditions down the promise chain by default.